Trouble Uploading CSV File to Shiny App: Data Not Readable and Column Names Not Recognized
I'm encountering issues when attempting to upload a CSV file into my Shiny app.
After saving my Excel data as a CSV file and uploading it to the Shiny app. I tried checking what was happening on https://shiny.posit.co/r/gallery/widgets/file-upload/ and I saw that with the 'header' option enabled, Shiny throws an error stating "more columns than column names."
Additionally, my Excel file contains two columns named 'Temperature' and 'A1.' However, when uploading the CSV file to Shiny, these column names are being interpreted as data points within the columns rather than as actual column headers. See
picture
Furthermore, my data contains comma's (,) as decimal separators, which might be contributing to the parsing issues. I attempted to replace all comma's in the Excel file with periods (.) before exporting it to CSV, but this did not seem to resolve the problem.
I save my data by exporting my Excel file as a CSV UTF-8 format and then directly upload it into the app.
This is the excel.
This is what the csv looks like as txt:
Temperature;A1
71,85;5,62
71,79;5,68
71,82;5,58
71,79;5,57
71,82;5,55
71,79;5,55
71,79;5,54
71,82;5,51

The Shiny app I use is: https://pavloh.shinyapps.io/hrmR/ From Pavlo Hrab (http://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.4491296)
Example data
df1 <- data.frame(Temperature = c(71.85, 71.79, 71.82, 71.79, 71.82, 71.79, 71.79,  71.82, 71.82), y = c(5.62, 5.68, 5.58,  5.57,  5.55, 5.55, 5.54,  5.51,5.52))

This is written in R and decimals are written as periods. My actual data is exported from an xlsx file to csv where decimals are written as decimals
script:
   # Look at file upload, As soon as file is uploaded prepare the data and save it
    observeEvent(input$hmr,{
        # Read the first line and define the delimiter. Then read the whole data
        L <- readLines(input$hmr$datapath, n = 1)
        if (grepl(";", L)) vals$df <- read.csv2(input$hmr$datapath) else vals$df <- read.csv(input$hmr$datapath)
        # Drop NA columns
        vals$df <- vals$df[,colSums(is.na(vals$df))<nrow(vals$df)]
        write.csv(vals$df, file = "data.csv", row.names = F)
        
         })
    # Drop data from master dataframe (columns - individual results)
    observeEvent(input$drop,{
        to_drop <- input$drop_txt
        # First split the input by comma, then by range
        commas <- strsplit(to_drop, ",")
        ranges_drop <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(unlist(commas)[grepl("-", unlist(commas))], "-")))
        ind_col_drop <- trimws(unlist(commas)[!grepl("-", unlist(commas))])
        # Logic on how to split the data - like an individual column, or by range of columns. First go by ranges
        if (length(ranges_drop) > 0) {
            vals$df <- vals$df%>%
            select(!ranges_drop[1]:ranges_drop[2])
        }
        if (length(ind_col_drop) > 0){
            vals$df <- vals$df%>%
            select(-one_of(ind_col_drop))
        }
        # Set recluster to true
        vals$kmeans_cluster_actions <-  TRUE
    })
    # If reset button is triggered -> reset the daatframe (TO-DO: Add additional values change to recompute everything)
    observeEvent(input$reset,{
        vals$df <- read.csv("data.csv")
    })

Can someone please advise on how I can adjust my Excel file or export settings to ensure that the CSV file is readable by the Shiny app?
I tried uploading my data in the app expecting it to show my the melting curve analysis based of my data input. But I keep receiving errors.

What do the contents of the CSV file look like exactly? CSV stands for "comma separated values", but it looks your might actually have data that uses semicolons as delimiters.

@MrFlick I have added a picture of what my file looks like!

The sample you started with uses read.csv and does not allow you to change the dec= parameter specify how numbers are interpreting. You can change the form so you can set that parameter as well, or switch it to use read.csv2 which default to a semicolon field separator and comma decimal separator.

@MrFlick im already using read.csv2. I tried changing it by splitting by semicolon commas <- strsplit(to_drop, ";") but I doesn't seem to work.

I believe the data format issue to be a red herring. See the below reprex where example data is downloaded, subset, and formatted in order to be similar to OP's data and then written out as either:

example_write.csv.csv (comma separated with decimals)
example_write.csv2.csv (semicolon separated with commas)

Either of these files can be uploaded to the app https://pavloh.shinyapps.io/hrmR/ and processed successfully.
Instead I posit OP's data are simply unfit for the analyses.
# download and unzip example file
zip_file <- "hrmR-v0.1-alpha.zip"
download.file(
  "https://zenodo.org/records/4491296/files/pavlohrab/hrmR-v0.1-alpha.zip?download=1", 
  zip_file, 
  mode = "wb"
)
unzip(
  zip_file, 
  "pavlohrab-hrmR-494cffb/example/example.csv", 
  junkpaths = TRUE
)

# read and subset example file to be similar to OP data structure
# but with way more observations
data <- read.csv("example.csv")
data <- data[, 1:2]
names(data)[2] <- "A1"

# write comma separated with decimals
write.csv(data, "example_write.csv.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
# notice formatting is as desired
cat(paste(readLines("example_write.csv.csv", 5), collapse = "\n"))
#> Temperature,A1
#> 65,3495.918232
#> 65.2,3507.963312
#> 65.4,3520.008391
#> 65.6,3532.053471

# write semicolon separated with commas
write.csv2(data, "example_write.csv2.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
# notice formatting is as desired
cat(paste(readLines("example_write.csv2.csv", 5), collapse = "\n"))
#> Temperature;A1
#> 65;3495,918232
#> 65,2;3507,963312
#> 65,4;3520,008391
#> 65,6;3532,053471

Created on 2024-05-07 with reprex v2.1.0
